# Show/Hide Clip Effect with Fade

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, animation, jquery-animate

Need help in figuring out how to add a **fade out/in** to the following:

```
$(function(){               
    $('#menu').stop(true, true).hover(function(){   
            $('.content').stop(true, true).delay(300).show(
                "clip",
                {direction: "vertical"}, 
                200       
            );                          
        },
        function(){ 
            $('.content').stop(true, true).hide( 
                "clip",
                {direction: "vertical"}, 
                200 
            );
        }); 
});
```

When the animation `clip` occurs on show/hide, I want it to fade in/out simultaneously with the `clip`, but currently it simply queues if I add `.animate` or `.fadeIn/Out`.

(Using **jQuery** and **jQuery UI**)

[Example jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hftpc/11/)

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you shows us a demo/example. Maybe code it up in [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Hi Alex, see: http://jsfiddle.net/Hftpc/11/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `.animate()` instead of `.fadeIn()`/`.fadeOut()`, it can be passed an option (`queue : false`) that can make the animation run at once, instead of placing it in the queue.

An example based on your code (just set opacity to zero by default):

```
$('.content')
    .stop(true, true)
    .show( "clip",{direction: "vertical"}, 800 )
    .animate({ opacity : 1 }, { duration: 800, queue: false });
```

[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bazmegakapa/Hftpc/15/)

Comment: Yay! Thanks, I tried this, but the queue false didn't initially work for me (must have done something wrong).